# How to get style in Elm

Tags: css, properties, attributes, elm

I'm starting with Elm and when you want to set style you can simply embed it on your component: `Html.Attribute.style List (String, String)`

But I can't find a way to ***get*** the style instead of set. What I need, actually, is the `line-height` (CSS attribute) of a specifc `Html msg`. I read a little about using a custom decoder (with `Json.Decode.at`) but I still didn't get it.

Comment: Could you explain in a little bit more detail what you're trying to accomplish? What do you need the line-height for?

Comment: I'm actually trying to implement a fluid textarea (with height increasing according to line count). Usually we do this by calculating line-height, as css doesn't have this by default. https://github.com/ohanhi/autoexpand is an example but it doesn't worked here, and I didn't like the way it works. Also, I didn't understand the code.

Comment: For the record, I think it's strange that CSS does not have a "line size" unit of measurement. It would make life so much easier if we could write `div {height: 3lines}`. Instead, they invent more and more units of measurements that add nothing new to what we have already.

Comment: I think they should have something like `overflow: set-the-width-according-to-content-overflow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mateus, I'm just starting w/ elm so take this for what it's worth.

When you receive an event you can interrogate the event target to get information about it, or a relative element. Apparently, absent an event there isn't (currently) a way to "reach into" the DOM at pull out values willy-nilly (see *1 below)

Resources:

*1: https://medium.com/@debois/elm-the-dom-8c9883190d20

*2: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/building-custom-dom-event-handlers-in-elm

Back to your question, turns out what's set as style [(key1, val1)...(keyn, valn)] gets turned into {key1:val1, ...keyn:valn}. (I find this by debugging elm's transpiled code ... then see documentation elsewhere about it; go figure.)

See below to get line-height specifically. I suppose it could be more useful to get a list of all styles. Revised sample follows:

```
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (on)
import Json.Decode 


main =
  beginnerProgram { model = "", view = view, update = update }

type Msg = Attr StyleStruct

type alias StyleStruct =
  {lineHeight: String}


view model =
  div []
    [ button [ id "btn"
        , class "cls"
        , style [("color", "green"), ("line-height", "3em")]
        , myOnClick Attr ]
        [ text "Show line-height" ]
    , div [] [ text ("(" ++ model ++ ")")]
    ]

update msg model =
  case msg of
    Attr v1 ->
      toString v1

targetStyle =
  Json.Decode.map StyleStruct
    (Json.Decode.at ["target", "style"] styleStructDecoder)

styleStructDecoder =
  Json.Decode.at ["line-height"] Json.Decode.string


myOnClick : (StyleStruct -> msg) -> Html.Attribute msg
myOnClick tagger =
  on "click" (Json.Decode.map tagger targetStyle)
```

Comment: I thanks for your answer. I already know how to use this method, but dido you ever triend changing "id" with "style"? I don't know how to parse it.

Comment: Did you mean style, or class? If the latter, use the property (rather than attribute), here `className`. I've edited the response above

Comment: I meant style. Like, on javascript, [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).

Comment: Ah, I see. My mistake. revised above.

Comment: Thanks, it is what I need. I was thinking how I could decode a list of tuples, but it seems that decoding is a little different than using the default Html.Attribute.style function.