# Decoding Html.Attribute.style

Tags: elm

n00b. This is a follow-up question to my own answer at [How to get style in Elm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43398381/how-to-get-style-in-elm/43415983). In the question the OP needed only a specific style item `line-height`, which was easy enough. In looking into getting all style items I'm at the moment stumped.

In this Ellie I've made a made an example of decoding a Json object that represents an Elm-applied style: https://ellie-app.com/VNs4WGpNDNa1/0 . So far so good.

However in this Ellie, displaying a specific style item (`color`) works, but displaying the entire style structure doesn't: https://ellie-app.com/VN8X9kHbBfa1/0 . (In this Ellie I'd also like to combine the `colorDecoder` and `styleDecoder` functions by somehow parameterizing them ... though that's a battle for another time!)

Guidance much sought :-) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript value in `target.style` is of type [CSSStyleDeclaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration), which is mostly made up of fields whose values are strings, but also contains some fields that are not strings. For example `length` is a number and `setProperty` is a function.

Your decoder assumes that all values are strings, which they aren't, so it silently fails.

If you only want those values of type string, you can use `Json.Decode.maybe Json.Decode.string` to find those values that are of type string, then `Json.Decode.andThen` and `List.filterMap` to keep only the string values:

```elm
styleFormatDecoder =
    Json.Decode.keyValuePairs (Json.Decode.maybe Json.Decode.string)
        |> Json.Decode.map justStringVals

justStringVals : List (String, Maybe String) -> List (String, String)
justStringVals =
    List.filterMap (\(key, maybeVal) ->
        case maybeVal of
            Just val -> Just (key, val)
            Nothing -> Nothing)
```

Comment: True -- I'd noticed that passing a nonsense string to `at` simply had it fail silently, *and* I'd blithely (and incorrectly) assumed from `VirtualDom.js/organizeFacts(factList)` that not only were everything stringified, but that I wouldn't be returned more styles than set there (i.e. no inherits, compute, etc). Thanx (again) :-) !